# evaluation of $\nabla \cdot ( \boldsymbol{B}(\boldsymbol{x}) \cdot \boldsymbol{B}^{T}(\boldsymbol{x}) )$

Tags: matrices, derivatives, tensor-products, tensors

i have a symmetric positive matrix $\boldsymbol{D}(\boldsymbol{x})$ which can be decomposed as:

$\boldsymbol{D}(\boldsymbol{x})$ = $\boldsymbol{B}(\boldsymbol{x}) \cdot\boldsymbol{B}^{T}(\boldsymbol{x})$

if I do apply the divergance to $\boldsymbol{D}(\boldsymbol{x})$ what do i obtain?

(Note that in my notation the divergence is calculated with respect to the second index)

i made some calculus but i wanted to be sure i was correct:

$\nabla \cdot ( \boldsymbol{B}(x) \cdot \boldsymbol{B}^{T}(x) )$ = $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_{i}} B_{jk}(\boldsymbol{x})B_{ki}^{T}(\boldsymbol{x})\boldsymbol{e}_{j}=B_{ki}^{T}(\boldsymbol{x})\frac{\partial}{\partial x_{i}}B_{jk}(\boldsymbol{x}) \boldsymbol{e}_{j}+B_{jk}(\boldsymbol{x})\frac{\partial}{\partial x_{i}}B_{ki}^{T}(\boldsymbol{x}) \boldsymbol{e}_{j}$

which in tensorial notation can be written as:

$\nabla \cdot ( \boldsymbol{B}(x) \cdot \boldsymbol{B}^{T}(x) )=\boldsymbol{B}^{T}(\boldsymbol{x}):(\nabla \boldsymbol{B}^{T}(\boldsymbol{x}))+\boldsymbol{B}(\boldsymbol{x})\cdot(\nabla \cdot \boldsymbol{B}^{T}(\boldsymbol{x}))$

am I correct or am I totally wrong?

Comment: In your last line what do "$:$" and "$\cdot$" mean? Do they have to do with which of the indices you end up acting on?

Comment: $\cdot$ is the scalar product between matrices; while $:$ is the double scalar product; for which I mean $\boldsymbol{A}:\boldsymbol{C} = A_{ij}C_{ji}$ i hope it is clear...However what is important is whether the equivalence written by components is correct or not...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is totally correct.

In your final line, the term "$\boldsymbol{B}^{T}(\boldsymbol{x}):(\nabla \boldsymbol{B}^{T}(\boldsymbol{x}))$" is a bit ambiguous since $(\nabla \boldsymbol{B}^{T}(\boldsymbol{x}))$ has three indices and it's not clear which of them the indices of $\boldsymbol{B}^{T}(\boldsymbol{x})$ are being contracted with.

Comment: true, but the indicial notation is just above (and I was just concerned about the correctness of that one)